# Getting Errorcode 80C805E2 when syncing E-mails for a week now

Tags: email, outlook

Since last saturday I can't sync the e-mails of my hotmail account anymore. 
Everytime I try to sync I get the errorcode 80C805E2 (I'm going into mails, press sync and get this error after a short time).

I already tried disabling chat message backup and restarted the phone to no avail, the error still persists. Retyping my password in the mail settings didn't help neither.

I even tried clearing my inbox but it did not change the error.

How do I resolve this error? Or do I need to factory reset my phone (which would be a real nuisance).

Cheers Sam

Comment: Please add to your question where did you see this error. I think it is in the `email+accounts`.

Comment: When I go into the inbox, press sync, I'll get this error. I'll get it, too, when I go to the account in the settings.

Comment: I know you mentioned you had disabled chat backup, but did you also disable text message backup? That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: Owen, I disabled both chat and text to no avail :(

Answer (score 1):

Came across this in another [forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpemail/nokia-920-80c805e2/67f6542d-ea7d-481d-bf84-63ff59cea7aa?msgId=439a6603-66bd-4e48-93ed-29aedbc57e2b) which might be helpful.

> Open Settings
>
> Slide left
>
> click on Messaging
>
> turn ON on or OFF both of the below
>
> "Use Facebook chat" and "chat backup"
>
> Your sync should work just fine now.
>
> The error is because the above settings are dependent on another, "Use Facebook chat" has to be on if "chat backup"  is on already. That is why the error.

I've fixed some email account sync issues by removing the email account and re-adding it. I've not had to factory reset the handset, removing just the email account in question has worked.

Comment: I read the same hint several times, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Andy Davies answer is almost correct, for me at least. I had this problem went to messaging and turned off text message backup. My Microsoft account would sync after that.

Answer (score 1):

Error code : 80C805E2 showing Cannot synchronise mail

Go to settings-email+accounts and delete your mail account from the list. Dont worry your account will not be affected and only its information will be taken out from the phone. Again you add the account by pressing + new account and synchronise.

Hope your problem is resolved :)

Comment: You can delete the primary hotmail account under which the phone is registered? I thought this impossible (and can't check since after 10 days without solution I resetted my phone).

Comment: Thanks, by deleting n again adding account problem solved